# One to Many Associate objects with sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

If I have two objects Project and Task associated with one-to-many relation

```
 Project.hasMany(Task)     
 var Pro1 = Project.build({...}).save();
```

Now when I set a new task to one person after saving it

```
var task = Task.build({ ... }).save().success(function(t1)){
     project.setTasks([t1]).success(function() {
            // saved!
      })
})
```

the first task works fine, but with the second task I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'omitNull' of undefined
    at  {myhome}/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many-single-linked.js:21:65
```

How can add more tasks to the previous, and be able to get them later with

```
Pro1.getTASKs
```

Comment: you are at 1.5.0-alpha right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sadly your code is kinda strange, as you are using different variable names in those three code examples. However, this is how you would do it: https://gist.github.com/3040391

In order to add other tasks you can do `project.addTask(myNewTask)`

Comment: thanks for replying, but when I add a second task 

   project.setTasks([ task ]).success(function() {
     Task.create({name: 'asma'}).success(function(t2){
        project.setTasks([t2]).success(function() {
          project.getTasks().success(function(tasks) {
              console.log(tasks.map(function(t){ return t.values }))
          })}) })
         project.getTasks().success(function(tasks) {
        console.log(tasks.map(function(t){ return t.values }))
      }) }) })  })
I get this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'omitNull' of undefined

Comment: interesting :) thanks for reporting. use the 1.4.1 build to get rid of that

Comment: dude how to do if i want to create and add multiple objects ?

Answer (score 0):

this issue is fixed in 1.5.0-beta :) go for it!